# What is the meaning of the phrase "we-find-each-other's-lame-jokes-funny vibe"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I learned the specified phrase from the book "Revolution 2020" by "Chetan Bhagath".

> I didn't like the **we-find-each-other's-lame-jokes-funny vibe** between Raghav and Aarti

What is the meaning of **we-find-each-other's-lame-jokes-funny vibe**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have read the book "Revolution 2020". Here the Author and Aarti are best friends for years. And Raghav is close friend of author only and not for Aarti. How ever when they met at local bakery for snacks, Raghav and Aarti having good time by making fun of their career aspirations and author doesn't like to make fun on career. And he also doesn't like Aarti moving with Raghave so close. He expressed the same through this phase.

Answer (score 10):

People who know each other well - especially close friends - often share "in jokes." These are sayings, or references to past events, which are funny to those "in the know," but obscure, unfunny, or even offensive to those unfamiliar with the reference. The "vibe" is the sense or attitude that the two share or project.

For example, someone very knowledgeable about a topic may give off a vibe of confidence (or, less attractively, of arrogance).

In this case, Raghav and Aarti share a sense of humor (or perhaps the history described above), and that shared "vibe" is offensive to the writer.

You may think of it as the uncomfortable feeling you get when, at a party, you walk up to two friends who are speaking, and they stop talking and just look at you - you know you're on the outside, not part of the group.

Comment: +1 for conveying that the vibe is about more than just bad jokes - but about exclusivity to their clique.

Answer (score 2):

The long, hyphenated expression describes a behavior shared by the characters Raghav and Aarti. It means that Raghav and Aarti both tell bad jokes, and Raghav and Aarti get enjoyment out of those bad jokes. They probably think, "Our jokes are terrible, but they're *awesome* because they're terrible. We don't care what you think."

I would infer from this that no one else finds Raghav and Aarti's jokes funny, and that the narrator thinks that they are pretentious.

The hyphenated construction draws attention to the artificiality of Raghav and Arti's "vibe" to make clear that the narrator is aware that it is a big charade.

Comment: Yes; the usual construction would not use the contrived, attention-grapping hyphen-peppered pre-modifier: _I didn't like the fact that Raghav and Aarti have a rather odd relationship in that they find each other's lame jokes funny._ Used sparingly, multi-hyphenated compound adjectives in the attributive position can be very effective:  _I didn't like the we-find-each-other's-lame-jokes-funny vibe between Raghav and Aarti._ The modern don't-be-afraid-to-make-up-your-own-multi-hyphenated-pre-modifying-adjective trend could, of course, soon become a flogged-to-death practice.

Answer (score 2):

My wife and I have a large number of "in-jokes" and sayings that other people either don't understand or do understand but don't find funny. And, of course, they aren't funny to anyone else...they are less jokes than they are relationship/friendship glue. This is the "vibe" that is being referred to but, in this context, the author is clearly put off by it.